# PHP - How can I use curly bracket with variable correctly?

Tags: php, syntax, curly-braces

I read php document and I saw this:

```
    class foo{
        var $bar = 'I am a bar';
    }

    $foo = new foo();
    $identity = 'bar';

    echo "{$foo->$identity}";
```

And I saw somebody wrote like this:

```
if (!isset($ns->job_{$this->id})){
   //do something
}
```

But when I tried with this code, It didn't work:

```
$id1 = 10;

$no = 1;

echo ${id.$no};
```

Can you guys tell me why it didn't work and when I can use braces with variable correctly?

Comment: Your last example worksks fine and prints 10. Are you on a version of PHP earlier than 5.0?

Comment: @Borodin I use php 5.3.8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Live example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/iOnnzI)

Brackets can be used on object types, for instance, to simulate a array index. Supposing that `$arr` is an array type and `$obj` an object, we have:

```
$arr['index'] ===
$obj->{'index'}
```

You can make it more fun, for instance:

```
$arr["index{$id}"] ===
$obj->{"index{$id}"}
```

Even more:

```
$arr[count($list)] ===
$obj->{count($list)}
```

**Edit: Your problem** --
[variable of variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

```
// Your problem
$id1 = 10;
$no = 1;
$full = "id{$no}";

var_dump($$full); // yeap! $$ instead of $
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you *expecting*?

```
$id = 10;
$no = 1;
echo "${id}.${no}";  // prints "10.1"
```

Comment: sorry no, I want to print $id1 by 1 is variable.